Ошибка при формировании запроса к Seller API OZON
Я пытаюсь получить список отправлений скриптом R на Озоне в соответствии с методом PostingAPI_GetFbsPostingListV3, для чего использую пакет httr2.
Фрагмент кода:
req <- httr2::request("https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v3/posting/fbs/list") %>%
  req_headers(
    'Client-Id' = ClientID,
    'Api-Key' = API_KEY,
    'Content-Type' = "application/json"
  ) %>%
  req_method("POST") %>%
  req_body_json(list(
    dir = "asc",
    filter = list(
      since = "2024-10-21T00:00:00Z",
      to = "2024-10-23T00:00:00Z",
      status = "delivering"
    ),
    Limit = 100,
    offset = 0,
    with = list(
      analytics_data = TRUE,
      barcodes = TRUE,
      financial_data = TRUE,
      translit = FALSE
    )
  ))

response <- req %>% req_perform(verbosity = 3)

При исполнении запроса выдаётся ответ сервера:

invalid SellerFbsPostingListRequestV3.Limit: value must be inside range (0, 1000]

Вначале я было подумал, что дело в том, что req_body_json() воспринимает значение пары Limit = 100 как тип double.
Попробовал следующее:
Limit = as.integer(100)

Результат не изменился. Кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной ошибкой? В чём может быть проблема?

Limit на самом деле limit (в документации Озон ошибка).
Смена заглавной буквы на строчную всё меняет — всё сразу начинает работать.
